# Making a pointer for a QPushButton from QStringList

Tags: c++, pointers, grid, qt-creator, qpushbutton

i was making aAxB grid of QPushButtons
[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYpPE.png)
and Stored all their names to a QStringList 
like so

```
           QString Enemy_name = "Enemy_n"+QString::number(counter);
        counter++;

            QPushButton *Enemy_ship =new QPushButton(ui->Enemy);
            Enemy_ship->setObjectName(Enemy_name);
            Enemy_ship->setGeometry(15*b,15*i,10,10);
            Enemy_ship->setVisible(true);

            Enemy_name += "G";

            Enemy_names += Enemy_name;
        }
    }
    Enemy_list = Enemy_names.split("G");
```

The stored values in the list are being used in here
where i get some convert errors
this is the code

```
void MainWindow::lastrow(){
int n=0;

QString firstinrow = Enemy_list[0];     //Getting QPushButton Objectname from the list
QPushButton *b = firstinrow;            //Making pointer *b for the object name
QString temp;                           //Same but temporary
QPushButton *btemp;                     //...
do{
    n++;                                //Counter for list position
    temp = &Enemy_list[n];              //Getting object name from position n in the list
    *btemp = temp;                      //temp button pointer
}while(!ui->*b->geometry.y() == ui->*btemp->geometry.y());      //checking Y of those 2 for not same Y
   // QString lastinrow = &Enemy_list[n-1];
}
```

the errors

```
E:\QT\Try\mainwindow.cpp:81: Chyba: cannot convert 'QString' to 'QPushButton*' in initialization
     QPushButton *b = firstincol;
                      ^

E:\QT\Try\mainwindow.cpp:86: Chyba: invalid conversion from 'QString*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
     temp = &Enemy_list[n];
          ^

E:\QT\Try\mainwindow.cpp:87: Chyba: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QPushButton' and 'QString')
         *btemp = temp;
                ^

E:\QT\Try\mainwindow.cpp:88: Chyba: 'b->QWidget::geometry' does not have class type
     }while(!ui->*b->geometry.y() == ui->*btemp->geometry.y());


E:\QT\Try\mainwindow.cpp:88: Chyba: 'btemp->QWidget::geometry' does not have class type
 }while(!ui->*b->geometry.y() == ui->*btemp->geometry.y());
                                      ^
                  ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want an associative array (key:value, key1:value...), when "key" is name of button and value is object button.

In Qt, QMap is used for this.

Here is a simple demonstration of how to use this.

file mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMap>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void whoIam();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QMap<QString, QPushButton *> list;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

file mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
        button->setGeometry(i*70,20,60,40);
        button->setObjectName("key_"+QString::number(i));
        button->setText(button->objectName());
        connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(whoIam()));
        list.insert(button->objectName(),button);
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::whoIam()
{
  QPushButton *button = dynamic_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());
  QString message = QString("Hi, I am a QPushButton %1\nI am at x: %2, y: %3.")
          .arg(button->objectName())
          .arg(button->geometry().x())
          .arg(button->geometry().y());
  QMessageBox::information(this,"Information",message);

  button = dynamic_cast<QPushButton *>(list["key_1"]);
  message = QString("Hi, I am a QPushButton %1\nI am at x: %2, y: %3.")
            .arg(button->objectName())
            .arg(button->geometry().x())
            .arg(button->geometry().y());
  QMessageBox::information(this,"Information",message);
}
```

In constructor i create 10 button, setup his parameters, connect action clicked to my function (private slot: whoIam()) and insert button to list.

In whoIam(), I used dynamic_cast to cast QPushButton. For the first time, to get information about the object that triggered the event, the second time, as a sample call to the key variable "key_1" from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify what the problem is? As it a compiler writes, it is not possible to make a `QPushButton` form a `QString` and so on due to the errors. You cannot uderstand what is wrong or what? I am sorry, not enough raiting to write it in the comment. Will delete it after, or give a full answer.

Comment: I have a string list with the object names and i want to take the object name from the list and read its geometry to find out if it does pass the condition (not same y in geometry)